# How can I keep unique keys unique across partitioned databases?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to scale out a MySQL database, so we're going for sharding scheme where data is partitioned by userID to live on various MySQL instances. Each MySQL database will hold a full copy of a userID<->databaseID, and also hold all of the data for its particular set of users.

- what's a good way to allocate unique user indexes in this setup? (auto-incrementing the userID obviously fails)
- what's a good way to allocate unique indexes for all of the various data that is user-dependent (e.g. a table of the user's addresses) AND supports the ability to easily migrate the user's data from one server to another (for example, in case I want to re-balance the data across different DB instances).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A composite key of a tuple of (shard ID, user ID).

Comment: What happens if I want to add or remove DB server to meet demand? I don't expect that the userID will live indefinitely on the first shard I assign it to.

Comment: You will have a master list of shards being assigned somewhere. Make sure they are all assigned unique IDs which are not recycled. After that, it doesn't matter when a user ID moves among shards; shard IDs are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: If I allocate the row [shardID=1, userID, x,x,x] to shard1 and then rebalance this data and other shard1 data to other shards, then I can never re-use '1' as a shard ID without risking doubly allocating an ID (because the shard can't check if the ID exists). 

Or would the solution be to retain the highest-until-now userID for shard1 and allocate userIDs from that value upwards on that shard.

Comment: @user48956 - yes, that makes sense for your situation. It should be the default behaviour anyway, shouldn't it? I mean, a MySQL shard, which is a database instance, will assign monotonically increasing unique row IDs to autoincrement columns in a table. If you then rebalance some of these rows into another shard, the original shard should still continue incrementing from where it left off--it shouldn't recycle ID numbers that are now missing.